# MiniProfiler.Ef issue with EntityFramework6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mvc-mini-profiler

I have updated EF5 to 6 and  MiniProfiler.Ef to 2.0.3

I am having issues to run the application now. As per the suggestion by https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/pull/142 I have updated my Web.Config to access the MiniProfiler Provider for the EntityFramework.

But the MiniProfiler.EntityFramework doesn't have a method named `EFProfiledSqlClientDbProviderServices` and I couldn't find a method which returns `System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices`

Could anyone please help me to fix the issue to connect EntityFramework6 with MiniProfiler.Ef

Side note I am using StructureMap for depedency injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EF6 nuget has been published. It is available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.EF6/) and can be installed using `Install-Package MiniProfiler.EF6 -Pre`

In order to use it you will need to also install [MiniProfiler v3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler) (your question references the old repository).

To initialize, simply call the following in your application startup logic:

```
using StackExchange.Profiling.EntityFramework6;

...

protected void Application_Start()
{
    MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
}
```

Be sure to call this before using EF in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework 6 support wasn't officially released yet. You can find the code in [StackExchange.Profiling.EntityFramework6](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/tree/master/StackExchange.Profiling.EntityFramework6) project on github with instruction [here](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/pull/9#issuecomment-27850376).

Answer (score 1):

I have an issue in that after loading MiniProfiler and MiniProfiler.EnitiyFramework6. MiniProfiler runs fine, but when I add to my Applcation_Start in Global.asax

MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();

I get this:

An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in MiniProfiler.EntityFramework6.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'MiniProfiler, Version=3.0.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b44f9351044011a3' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem. You should try with:
`Update-Package MiniProfiler -Version 3.0.11`